# Adobe air player : Android

Tags: android, flash, mobile, air, adobe

Does Android support adobe air player ? I am new to these mobile technologies. I know, Adobe not going to give support for flash player for android platform. Is it also true for Air Player ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/adobe-air-2-6-for-android-is-now-available.html

Yes, according to the adobe website, the AIR player can be downloaded from the Android Market.

Comment: Nice. At list I can try to run flex application on Air player for android platform. Adobe confused me everytime, they dont give support for flash player but they are ok with AIR player. Again this article is more then one year old but thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: No problem, I would expect that you'd have to recode stuff for Android though as code that runs well on a PC may make a phone struggle. It doesn't matter how old the article is, it's still up-to-date :P